# Is this code of matrix expo logarithmic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication, fibonacci

I wanted to calculate the nth fibonnaci number in logarithmic time. So , I have written this function

```
vector<vector<ll> > expon(ll k)
{
    if(k==1)
    {
        vector<vector<ll>> A({{1,1},{1,0}});
        return A;
    }
    auto A = expon(k/2);
    ll tmp[2][2] = {{0,0},{0,0}};
    for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<2;++j)
            for(int k=0;k<2;++k)
                tmp[i][j] += (A[i][k]*A[k][j])%modv;

    vector<vector<ll>> B({{tmp[0][0],tmp[0][1]},{tmp[1][0],tmp[1][1]}});
    if(k%2)
        return vector<vector<ll>>({{(tmp[0][0]+tmp[0][1])%modv,tmp[0][0]},{(tmp[1][0]+tmp[1][1])%modv,tmp[1][0]}});
    else
        return B;
}
```

But some how I think its taking too much time . So I was wondering , is it actually logarithmic? I mean my code.

Comment: "logarithmic" could be the complexity, that doesn't mean the algorithm is fast :)

Comment: How is too much time? Have you used optimization flags for compilation?  How does the running time increase in comparison with `k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity is logarithmic, but the implementation is suboptimal. You don't need a recursion and you don't need to create separate vector instances for each power of the matrix. Another remark - you have duplicate variable `k` which would lead to a warning depending on compiler settings.

There is a way to check if a given code snippet is logarithmic - measure the amount of time it takes for input `n`, `n^2`, `n^4`. If the complexity is logarithmic, each test should take approximately twice as much as the previous one(also keep in mind the measuring may be inaccurate for small durations).

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is **O(k*logn)** which is technically **O(logn)** but the constant k might be big as you create vector at every recursion which is memory allocation so it is slow.

Try using iterative solution :-

```
mat ans =[1,1,1,1];

while(k>0) {

  if(k&1) {

       ans = ans*a;
  }
  k=k>>1;
  a = a*a;
}
```

As you can notice this is `O(logn)` and does not need reallocation but a two 2X2 matrix.